# Fill array with random numbers & print to screen

Tags: c, arrays

I am a beginner trying to fill a 3x5 an 2D array with random number then display the high, low, and average values to the screen. I can't get my array to print to the screen. Can someone please help?

```
#include <stido.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void){
    int array [3][5];
    int practice_array;
    int i, row, col;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for ( row = 0; row < 3; row +1){

      for ( col = 0; col < 5; col +1){

        array[row][col] = (rand()%10000) + 1;
      }
    }
    practice_array = array[row][col];
    printf("%d", array[row][col]);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You need to put the `printf` command inside the loops for `row` and `col` as well; or, if you first want to calculate the arrays and *then* print them, repeat the loops for printing.

Comment: And `#include <stido.h>` doesn't exists, it's `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: My array is printing incorrectly, it won't stop adding nubers, can you please help me?

Comment: And² `row +1` should be `row = row + 1`, or `row += 1`, or `row++`, or `++row` (and same for `col`)

Comment: Fix your indentation. At the very least it will show you the `row` and `col` variables in the `printf` line are not used correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You've 3 main problems:**

**1.** As Jongware says in his comment the `printf` should be inside the loops, not outside.

**2.** `#include <stido.h>` doesn't exists, it's `#include <stdio.h>`

**3.** `row +1` should be `row = row + 1`, or `row += 1`, or `row++`, or `++row` (in this case we usually use `row++` or `++row`). Of course you need to do the same for `col`

**Secondary:**

**a.** `practice_array` and `i` are useless here.

**b.** you probably forgot the `\n` in the `printf`.

**I corrected your code + I added min, max, and average values:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS_NB 3
#define COLS_NB 5
#define MIN_VAL 1
#define MAX_VAL 10000

int main(void)
{
    int array[ROWS_NB][COLS_NB];
    int row;
    int col;
    int val;
    int min = MAX_VAL;
    int max = MIN_VAL;
    int avg = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (row = 0; row < ROWS_NB; ++row)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS_NB; ++col)
        {
            val = (rand() % (MAX_VAL - MIN_VAL)) + MIN_VAL;
            if (val < min)
                min = val;
            else if (val > max)
                max = val;
            avg += val;
            array[row][col] = val;
            //printf("%d ", val);/* uncomment if you want to print the array */
        }
        //printf("\n");/* uncomment if you want to print the array */
    }
    avg /= ROWS_NB * COLS_NB;
    printf("min: %d\nmax: %d\naverage: %d\n", min, max, avg);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: +1 Good edits. Few followup comments. You may not need `i` anymore. The "\n" might look nicer if printed after the full row, not every element. You might want to add the code for computing and displaying high, low, and average.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just print array like that. Each element must be printed by it's own.

`for ( row = 0; row < 3; row++){
    for ( col = 0; col < 5; col++){
         printf ("%d ", array[row][col]);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

There are various things in the code I fixed for you.

The library you want to include is `stdio.h`
The value of col and row was not being updated correctly
and the `printf` statements need to go in the loops and print each value as it is popul

```
include <stdio.h>
include <math.h>
include <time.h>

int main (void)
{
    int array [3][5];
    int i, row, col;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for ( row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for ( col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            array[row][col] = (rand()%10000) + 1;
            printf("%d ", array[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```