# Problems displaying max & min values in 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

Hello  I am trying to populate an array with random values between 0 and 10000, display each to the screen with their location then calculate max, min, and average value in addition to thier locations. I am having trouble displaying the results. Can someone please help? 
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>

int array [3][5];
int practice_array;
int i, row, col, max, min,  sum, avg;

srand(time(NULL));

for ( row = 0; row < 2; row = row + 1){

    for ( col = 0; col < 4; col = col +1){

        array[row][col] = rand()%10000;

        practice_array = array[row][col];
        sum = array[row][col];
        avg = sum / 15;

        for(i =0; i< 8; i++){
            printf("The value in row %d col %d is %d\n",row, col,practice_array);
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    max = array[0];
    min = array[0];

    if (array[i] > max)
    {
        max = array[i];
    }
    else if (array[i] < min)
    {
        min = array [i];
    }
}

printf("The max value is %d in row %d, col %d\n", max, row,col);
printf("The min value is %d in row %d, col %d \n", min, row,col);
return (0);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill array with random numbers & print to screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874768/fill-array-with-random-numbers-print-to-screen)

Comment: @user3479702: Why don't you accept one of the answers to your previous quesion. Biduleohm's answer look pretty good. If you have doubts, you can ask questions right there :-)

Comment: I'm new to this. I didn't know that you could revise code on the same thread. Thanks for letting me know! Can you help me figure out why I'm unable to print?

Comment: Why you're unable to print what ? with which code (this topic or the other) ? please, be specific. //cc to @Arun

Comment: @arun On this topic-The min & max values are showing up as negative with the wrong placement. Also, when it prints each values & location, they are duplicated 5 times before printing the next value.

Comment: I'll make an answer because comments are too limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 3
#define COL 5

int main(){
    int array[ROW][COL];
    int practice_array;
    int i, row, col, max, min,  sum, avg;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for ( row = 0; row < ROW; row = row + 1){
        for ( col = 0; col < COL; col = col +1){
            array[row][col] = rand()%(10000+1);
            practice_array = array[row][col];
            sum += practice_array;
            printf("The value in row %d col %d is %d\n",row, col,practice_array);
        }
    }
    avg = sum / (ROW*COL);//unused

    int *pv = &array[0][0];
    max = min = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < ROW*COL; ++i){
        if (pv[i] > pv[max])
            max =i;
        if (pv[i] < pv[min])
            min = i;
    }
    printf("The max value is %d in row %d, col %d\n", pv[max], max/COL, max%COL);
    printf("The min value is %d in row %d, col %d\n", pv[min], min/COL, min%COL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking through you code I could see a few things that you still need to work on.

Don't forget all of that needs to be inside of the main method or the compiler will not know where to start. you will also need "#include <stdlib.h>" to get your srand to work.

If you try to find examples online on a simple srand being used, you will see what I mean. The variable sum is not finding the sum. You need to loop though all the locations and add them to the sum. It would then be easy to find the average using your method.

If you are looking to print out all of them, remember to also use that for loop and loop through every single location and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

First you should really use defines for constants (array sizes, ...) like I've shown to you on the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874768/fill-array-with-random-numbers-print-to-screen) otherwise your code is mess with magic numbers everywhere (for example in this code: 3, 5, 2, 4, 8, ...). And if you've to change a value, you need to change it everywhere; with a `define` you change it only once at one place.

*Also, when it prints each values & location, they are duplicated 5 times before printing the next value* this is because of this (completely useless) loop, just delete it and keep only the `printf`:

```
for(i =0; i< 8; i++){
    printf("The value in row %d col %d is %d\n",row, col,practice_array);
}
```

For everything else, as far as I can see, you don't have fully understood how loops are working. I suggest you to learn the basics of the loops before trying to use them with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to use step wise development by first building an array with simple numbers and printing it out. Then try adding random numbers to a specific location in each array position and so on with 2d stuff. It seems like you wrote down a bunch of code without stepping back and trying to run it a few times